# Entendiendo los commit de Git

Tags: git, git-push, git-commit

querria solventar una duda en cuanto a los `commit` de **git**
Supongamos el siguiente ejemplo:

> He creado un repositorio en **GitHub**, llamemoslo *ejemplo*. En *git bash* lo he linkeado a un directorio de mi pc para empezar a trabajar en dicho repositorio. Finalmente creo 1 rama llamada `main` (tendria en este punto la **rama main y la rama master**). Y empiezo a trabajar ya en **main**...

> **Main** en este punto tiene lo mismo que **master** pues ha sido creada ahora, y master no tiene nada. Por tanto no tienen nada ninguna de las dos ramas.

**1º cosa que hago**:

*Creo un fichero llamado `index.php`*. *Hago un* `git add index.php` *para añadir el fichero y un* `git commit -m " mi primer commiteo en este branch"` *para registrar el commit, finalmente lo subo con un* `git push origin main`. 
Con esto tiene rama **main** el fichero `index.php` ya subido.

**2º cosa que hago:**

*Añado al* `index.php` un `<h1>` *y luego* *commiteo*. *Luego añado un* `<p>` *y luego* *commiteo* . He añadido dos cosas pero **no he hecho push** hasta este punto tengo *2 commits en la recamara*, es decir, en local pero no en mi repositorio remoto. 
Ahora bien, cuando haga el push para subir los *commits*, estos *commits* ... 
**Pregunta:**  ¿Se subiran los dos commits de golpe? De ser asi, estos *commits* tendra la fecha del **momento que hice commit** o **del momento que hice push** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En respuesta a tu pregunta de si se subirían los commits de golpe: Sí, tú subes la rama completa.

Con respecto a la fecha. Es información propia del commit, no del push, así que en github te aparecerá el commit a fecha de ayer si hiciste el commit ayer pero has hecho push de tu rama hoy.

Comment: Muchas gracias, yo es que siempre hago `git add .`, `git commit -m "comentario"` y finalmente `git push origin branch_name` . Ahora que se eso, sera mucho mas comodo. :)

Comment: Normalmente con eso te debe bastar, pero si solo quieres añadir algunos archivos con `git add nombre_de_archivo` es muy útil. Y puedes modificar la fecha del commit con `git commit --date mi_fecha -m mi_comentario` si no recuerdo mal ;)

Answer (score 4):

Cuando haces un `git push`, git compara el commit que está a la cabeza de la rama remota con la historia de commits de la rama local, hasta encontrarlo. Entonces sube a la rama remota todos los commits que aparezcan a partir de ese.

Si no pudiera encontrar el último commit remoto en tu rama local, daría un error y el push no sería posible. Esto puede pasar si alguien (otro colaborador en el proyecto) había hecho un `push` antes que tú, ya que en ese caso el último commit que está en el remoto no lo tienes tú en local. Para resolver este problema tendrías que hacer un `git pull` para bajarte esos commits que otro había añadido y que tú no tenías. Eso causará una mezcla de tus cambios con los que vengan (como si hubieras hecho un merge de tu rama con la que viene del repositorio. A partir de ahí ya podrías hacer un `push`, que subiría tus commits y el commit del merge.

El push no afecta ni a las fechas ni a los autores de los commit, ni a niguna otra meta-información contenida en los commits. Tan sólo copia esos commits a otro ordenador (en este caso el de Github).

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias por las alcaraciones

Comment: Osea que cada vez que haga commit debe de de hacer git pull para bajarse lo ultimo?

Comment: @FreddyDaniel Debería hacer `pull` siempre que sepa que el repositorio remoto tiene nuevo material. Y si no está seguro puede hacer `pull` también por si acaso (si no hay nada nuevo no pasa nada). No hay por qué hacerlo antes de cada commit, pero si haces varios commits antes del pull, después tendrás que hacer una mezcla de lo que venga (la mezcla suele ser automática pero en algunos casos puede dar conflictos que haya que resolver manualmente si ambos teneis commits que afectan a un mismo fichero)